# Do i need to enable billing, if i want to write to Firebase from the server code using Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have not yet enable the billing. With my application I want to write to the Firebase Database from the server code.
I am using standard Google App Engine servlet module.
Do I need to enable billing to enable the write operation from the server?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no relation between being able to write from a server and the billing status of your Firebase Project.

Comment: Thanks Frank. When I am running the backend module locally, the same servlet code is writing data the Firebase database. But when I deploy this module, data is not being written. I was suspecting that as I have not enable the billing it might be the issue, but as you mentioned it is not. So any clues what might be happening here?